# What is the best way to find the inverse image of a function in python?

Tags: python

so I have a function that takes some constants and the value of my c variable and returns the value of my x and y variable like this:

```py
def fun(*constants, c):
    #Calculates some stuf to get x and y
    return x, y
```

(x,y) = fun(constants, c)

- All variables are real numbers
- c belongs between 0 and a positive value cmax
- The x,y points are ordered with respect to c
- The function produces a curve that is continuous in the x-y plane

What is the best way to approximate the value of c given a specific value of y?

[Edited]
Tim Roberts suggests to use scipy.optimize.fsolve and this almost works for me. Is there a way to tell the fsolve to look only for roots specified in a range of c, in my case between 0 and cmax?

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def fun(*constants, c):
    #Calculates some stuf to get x and y
    return x, y

def func(c):
    return fun(*constants, c)[1]-y_objective
    
gess0 = cmax/2
y_objective = 10
c_wanted = fsolve(func, [gess0])

print(c_wanted)
```

Comment: The inverse in general may not exist. Your function must be a bijection for the inverse to exist.

Comment: Might not be particularly helpful, but you could inspect the source code of `fun` and try to construct the inverse, assuming the "stuff to get y" is all algebraic. I believe sympy can also do this, which would be much easier.

Comment: Sorry I made some mistakes in my original question that I have corrected. Do you thing there is enough information?

Comment: Let's say as ldog pointed the inverts exist and as ddejohn pointed the source does not exist. The best way might be to do a fit to a range of data and calculate the inverse of the fit.

Comment: If the `x` and `y` points are ordered, then you can start with `c=0`, then bump `c` up until `y` is too large, then use binary search to find the closest value.

Comment: `scipy.optimize.fsolve` might help you here.

Answer (score 1):

The question as stated is quite broad and can delve into some deep mathematical results. I will attempt to answer your question as reasonably as possible below.

The set of assumptions you listed are AFAICT not general enough for an inverse to exist, even in a neighborhood around some region of interest.

However, let us instead assume that the conditions required of the inverse function theorem hold (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). The IFT gives a formula for the inverse derivative within a region where the conditions hold. You can then utilize the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute the inverse function in this region . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus.

The integration will need to be either done symbolically (very advanced) or can be approximated using quadrature. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: I may be off but my function cannot be written down in algebraic terms, I don't think this continous approach works for me.